# difference between values() and only()

Tags: django, django-queryset

what's the difference between using:

```
Blabla.objects.values('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

and

```
Blabla.objects.only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming `Blabla` has the fields in your question, as well as `field4`,

```
Blabla.objects.only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')[0].field4
```

will return the value of that object's `field4` (with a new database query to retrieve that info), whereas

```
Blabla.objects.values('field1', 'field2', 'field3')[0].field4
```

will give

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'field4'
```

This is because `.values()` returns a `QuerySet` that returns dictionaries, which is essentially a list of dicts, rather than model instances (`Blabla`).

Comment: Which method is more efficient `.values()` or `.only()` ?

Comment: @ParasGupta If you have to ask, use `.values()`. Mis-using `.only()` could bog down your application.

If used correctly, neither is more efficient except for the few bytes the compiler has to go through. Though, calling `.only()` is called only if you need the instance. If you're just looking for the data, use `.values()`.

Answer (score 24):

The answers given so far are correct, but they don't mention some of the differences in terms of queries. I will just report them.

#### `.get()`

```sql
# User.objects.get(email='user@email.com').username

SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."password", "users_user"."last_login", 
"users_user"."is_superuser", "users_user"."username", "users_user"."first_name", 
"users_user"."last_name", "users_user"."email", "users_user"."is_staff", "users_user"."is_active", 
"users_user"."date_joined", "users_user"."name"
FROM "users_user" 
WHERE "users_user"."email" = 'user@email.com'; args=('user@email.com',)
```

#### `.only().get()`

```sql
# User.objects.only('username').get(email='user@email.com')

SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."username" 
FROM "users_user" 
WHERE "users_user"."email" = 'user@email.com'; args=('user@email.com',)
```

#### `.values().get()`

```sql
# User.objects.values('username').get(email='user@email.com')

SELECT "users_user"."username" 
FROM "users_user" 
WHERE "users_user"."email" = 'user@email.com'; args=('user@email.com',)
```

As you can see, `only()` will also select the `id` of the record. This is probably because of the fact that it will output a model that you can later use, as the other answers mentioned.

Comment: oh interesting. that's a nice addition indeed. thanks for bringing it!

Answer (score 19):

`.values()` gives you "less than a model"; the items it returns are closer to dictionaries than full models, which means you don't get the model attributes but you also don't have to initialize full models.

`.only()` restricts the field list in the SQL to specific fields you care about, but still initializes a full model; it defers loading of the other fields until you access them (if at all).

Comment: The items it returns aren't *close to* dicts, they [*are* dicts](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/query.py#L946)

Answer (score 4):

`values()` returns `QuerySet` - which when iterated returns dictionaries representing the model. It does not return model objects.

`only()` is a way of restricting the columns returned, and ensuring that *only* those columns are returned *immediately* - which is why it is sometimes referred to as the opposite of `defer()` It is the equivalent of saying `SELECT foo, bar, zoo FROM` rather than the normal `SELECT [all columns] FROM`. It will return a `QuerySet` that can further be chained.